# Evaluating model fit for glmmTMB with beta distribution

Tags: goodness-of-fit, beta-distribution, beta-regression, glmmtmb

I am looking for a way to evaluate model fit (e.g. $R^2$, %deviance explained) for the following model:

```
m1 <- glmmTMB(AUC_indep ~ woody + dispersal +
              log_densitys + log_seedwts + I(log_seedwts^2) +
              (1 | modeltype), 
              family = beta_family, data = dater);
```

As far as I can tell, at least as of August 2018, neither `r.squaredGLMM()` from the package(`MuMIn`) OR `r2()` (https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/blob/master/glmmTMB/inst/misc/rsqglmm.R) have been fitted to work with the beta family. Specifically, the variance function isn't calculated.

I'm wondering if there's been any updates for the beta distribution OR any other way, or a work around, to evaluate goodness-of-fit.